# Can Javascript access the DOM of an Ajax text/html response?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom

I'm trying to use Ajax to fetch an HTML page and then pull out a div by it's ID, and insert that DIV into the current page. So the current page loads (via Ajax) a second page, pulls the div out of the Ajax response and inserts into the current page. However I am at a loss as unless the response is text/xml, I cannot use any DOM functions on it... can I?

Comment: If you only want 1 part of the page you don't need to use the dom. You can just split the string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Jquery (or other libraries??) will basically do all this for you. I highly recommend looking into this and not reinventing the wheel.

For query it would probably like:

```
// Make a call to url, with data 
$.ajax(
  { url: $url,
    data: $data, 
    dataType: 'xml',
    callback: function(returnData) { 
      // Jquery find <mytag attribute="foo">...</mytag> and store it in mydata
      var mydata = $(returnData).find('mytag[attribute=foo]');
      // Insert into current page to somewhere with class="after-me"
      $('.after-me').html(mydata);
   }
});
```

I may have the syntax wrong. But here is the docs: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options

Comment: The problem is the response returned is a complete HTML page and I only want part of that response. I am already using prototype, but I need to find a way to cast the string of HTML I receive into a DOM Document in order to traverse it.

Comment: I am not sure with prototype, but in Jquery that is what $(returnData) does. It takes whatever returnData is and allows you to search/find/etc as if it was part of the page.

Comment: For example, you can pass a string: var result = $('<span><a href="link">Link</a></span>').find('a'); 

and result would be the DOM object <a href="link">link</a>

Comment: I don't understand what I was doing wrong before. This works just as you described and what jQuery is doing is creating a `<div>` with `document.createElement`, NOT inserting the div into the page, inserting the HTML into the div's `innerHTML`, and accessing the div's childNodes. I swear I tried this and it didn't work... but I must have been wrong because I just tried and it certainly does work.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. slight update if you wish to pull a part of response data through some class or attribute. please try this out.
`success: function (responseHTMLData) {   $($(responseHTMLData).find('.className')).each(function() {
 console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});`

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.  [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/Xml/xml_parser.asp) you will find a resource for how to parse XML responses.

If you are loading it into the DOM tree that already exists (`innerHTML`), you should be able to call the standard DOM traversal functions you are used to.

Comment: Can I load it into innerHTML if it's an entire document tree? Including <html><head><body> and everything?

Comment: You can but that will invalidate the DOM.

Comment: why are you loading an entire doc tree? only load specific parts. you already have a tree with the html tag; why put another one in there?

Comment: @George IV, that's my problem. I don't have access to the backend, I can only write Javascript code, and I am accessing one HTML page via AJAX. It's a complete page and I want a way to extract a specific part out of the Ajax response.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about validity, since you are doing this dynamically using javascript, you can fill hidden element's innerHTML with your response data and then use any DOM/jQuery functions you wish

Answer (score 0):

In order to use jQuery to extract only a portion of an HTML document loaded via $.load() do this:

```
$('#dynamic').load('content.html #desiredElement');
```

.load will actually load the entire document, but the selector will force load to only return the selected portion of that document.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. This worked for me.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.example.com',
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (responseHTMLData) {   
        $($(responseHTMLData).find('.yourClassName')).each(function() {
            console.log($(this).attr('href'));
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url : "yourURL"
  data : $("#yourFormID").serialize(),
  async: true,
  success : function(resp) {
    // resp contains data in html form you want to find data in
    // <span class="error">some Error</span>
    var errorData = $(resp).find('span.error').text();   
    // errorData would have value "some Error"             
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

script tags will fail on any browser by any method.. so to access current page's dom apply the "eval" function on the script text which you currently requested.

i mean, if you have html like:

```
<div id="content">some html</div>
```

and you got the script text on server side like

```
content.innerHTML = "foo";
```

use the eval function on ajax response

```
function onXmlHttpAnswer()
{
   if(xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200)eval(xmlHttp.responseText);
}
```

Comment: You misunderstood -- the response from the server isn't javascript. It's a complete HTML page and I want to use javascript to extract one part of that response.

Comment: well, if other page placed on the same domain, create a iframe by javascript than set its src to your page, listen iframe's load event, and you can process directly iframe's content

Comment: Thanks Tolgahan ALBAYRAK... I may end up going that route.