# Regexp to pull input tags out of form

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to extract all the `<input >` tags out of a `<form>` tag. I have created a regexp which can identify the entire `<form>` tag and all the code up to the ending `</form>` but I cannot figure out how to match all the `<input[^>]+>` within that.

EDIT: The data is a string. I cannot use DOM functions because it's not part of the document. if I insert it into a hidden  tag, it changes the layout of the page because the string contains an entire HTML page including links to external stylesheets.

Comment: May I ask what you are planning to do with the result. There might be another and better way to do it than regex

Comment: I agree. Regular expressions are notoriously poor at handling nested grammars like HTML.

Comment: Yeah I know... what I am doing is trying to pull the <input> tags out of an AJAX result. But the AJAX result is a string so I can't use DOM functions on it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855404/can-javascript-access-the-dom-of-an-ajax-text-html-response

Comment: @Ayman, thanks for cleaning up my question, I didn't think to use backtics!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regexes are fundamentally bad at parsing HTML (see [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166) for why).  What you need is an HTML parser.  See [Can you provide an example of parsing HTML with your favorite parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773340) for examples using a variety of parsers.

Comment: I actually just read that. Know of any way using javascript to convert a string to a Document object I can use DOM functions on? The string is HTML, not XML, and I cannot insert it into the page nor use an iFrame. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855404/can-javascript-access-the-dom-of-an-ajax-text-html-response)

Comment: @Josh No, I don't (JavaScript is really my thing), but that is an interesting question.  If only there were a place to ask interesting questions...

Comment: @Chas. Thanks! Actually I am reading jQuery's source -- on that second link you provided someone claimed they were able to do this using jQuery.

Comment: that should have been "JavaScript is really NOT my thing".

Comment: @Chas. Owens -- I found the answer using DOM parsing. Which is what I wanted to do before but couldn't figure out how. Or rather, figured out how but must have had an error somewhere else and thought what I was trying to do wasn't possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you just use the DOM?

```
var inputFields = document.getElementById('form_id').getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0, l = inputFields.length; i < l; i++) {
    // Do something with inputFields[i] ...
}
```

If you must use regex:

```
var formHTML = document.getElementById('form_id').innerHTML;
var inputs = formHTML.match(/<input.+?\/?>/g);
```

Note, the above regular expression is not reliable and will not work in ALL situations, hence why you should use the DOM! :)

Comment: Wish I could use DOM. problem is I have a string not a Document object. Inserting string into the document causes document layout to change. Know of any way to parse an HTML string into a Document object w/o rendering it?

Comment: You could render it in a hidden iframe...

Comment: @J-P It is possible, using document.createElement() and innerHTML on that element. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855404/can-javascript-access-the-dom-of-an-ajax-text-html-response

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.createElement` to create some element and then (ab)use it's `innerHTML` property to create a DOM from a string:

```
var html = document.createElement("div");
html.innerHTML = "<form><input/><input/><input/></form>";

// now you can use dom methods, e.g. getElementsByTagName
var inputs = html.getElementsByTagName("input");
var foo = inputs[0].value; // ...
```

You might have to manually remove your `<html>` tags beforehand though as IE has trouble parsing full documents (if I remember correctly).