# $.ajax() in success doesn't update div with div from another file (the same id name)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two files html, both have div with the same name id = example. I'd like use $.ajax() to load content from second file and put instead current text in div in first file. Problem is that $(data).find('#example') doesn't return element #example. I know this error is in that I'm using the same id's name but after all I want to download this div from another file, so I do not understand. Can anyone explain?

index.html:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div id="example">one one one one </div>
```

contact.html:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">products</a></li>                        
    </ul>
</nav>
<div id="example">one one one one </div>
```

```js
$('nav a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = this.href;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,      
        success: function(date){
            $('#example').html($(date).find('#example'));
      }
   });
 });
```

Comment: You cannot run an AJAX call in one page and expect it to modify another page.

Comment: i run ajax on first page and i want modify only the first page

Comment: Should work assuming `contact.html` is a full page. If it is only the snippet shown use `filter()` instead of `find()`. See demo http://plnkr.co/edit/CoNXqxeJjAK7gS47QrfI?p=preview

Comment: Your URL needs to be a complete URL like @charlietfl suggests. IE: `http://localhost/contact.html`, not just `contact.html`

Comment: @codeninja no it doesn't if they are in same directory. `this.href` will return the full url anyway but can be a relative path also

Comment: @charlietfl is right - also, not sure if the POST is necessary or might result in a different page being returned?

Comment: @Sam is right...note in my demo I changed to GET

Comment: Check the solution given at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855404/can-javascript-access-the-dom-of-an-ajax-text-html-response

Comment: @charlietfl in your demo is right but when change 'filter' to 'find' we get problem which i meant. Hovewer when i bracket div#example another div#over ([http://plnkr.co/edit/bUOaxxabnWrHte1y1Rfz?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/bUOaxxabnWrHte1y1Rfz?p=preview)) it is work, and i don't know why.

Comment: I used `filter()` because that element is at root level. In a full page with a `<body>` you would use `find()`

Comment: Your demo has `#example` inside another element ...that is why `find()` works. Mine doesn't because I copied it from your question exactly

Comment: @charlietfl when in your demo change `contact.html` to full page and `filter` to `find` it doesn't work. It doesn't depend on is fullPage/snippet. I just show on my demo if we bracket this `#example` in another div it starts working even with `find`.

Comment: I found. The `find ()` doesn't work because in the ajax response my `div#example` is at the highest level, so it's not a descendant ( _find is   looking for descendants only_ ). If I surrounded `div#example` another element then `find ()` starts to work because `div#example` becomes a descendant. So for my case use  `filter()` is solution.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('nav a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = this.href;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,      
        success: function(response){
            $('#example').html($(response.data).find('#example'));
      }
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

https://gitlab.com/Piterden/mcmp-pyro/blob/1.0/addons/default/defr/mcmp-theme/resources/js/theme/init.js#L144